# Circular dependency conundrums

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

In my C++ project, I have an `Engine` class, a `Renderer` class and an `Object` class.

The instance of `Renderer` renders instances of `Object`.  However instances of `Object` add themselves or remove themselves from the list of things to render.

From a usability point of view, it should be possible to set whether an instance of `Object` is drawn or not from the `Object`, but without the circular dependency.

I have a possible solution to this problem, but I do not know if it is a good idea:

The update cycle in the game is done through an `Update()` function in the `Engine` class that calls the `Update()` functions for every object.  When it comes to call the `Update()` function for each instance of `Object`, I could set it to check for two boolean variables in the `Object` class.  One, for whether it should be drawn, and one for whether it is actually being drawn.  This should thus allow for an instance of `Object` to be added or removed from the list of things to render as required.

**Is it a good idea to do it this way?  Is this way efficient or is there a better way without the circular dependency?**

**EDIT:**
I have rewritten my question for greater clarity and moved the second part to a new question where it was probably more relevant and to avoid confusing things further here.

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly... but I think that you should not add a reference to `Renderer` to the `Object`. Instead, when `Object::Update` is called, return whether the object should be added/removed to the drawing list, and let `Engine` do the insert/delete in the `Renderer` list. That way the dependency is `Engine -> Renderer` and you surely already have that.

Comment: This is the alternative I came up with as I mentioned in my Question, but I'm not sure if it's an inefficient way of doing this, and/or whether there's a better alternative.

Comment: You can forward-declare a class in another header if you only use pointers or references to it, and include the real header in the cpp. It doesn't sound like you'll ever need to completely separate these classes so I wouldn't be too concerned.

Comment: I'm already using a forward declaration of `Renderer` in my `Object` class, but ideally I shouldn't need to do this.  An instance of `Object` shouldn't be directly interacting with the instance of `Renderer`.  This is what my question is all about the circular dependencies I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I really understand the intention. However, i would like to revisit your original question:

> Currently, in order for an instance of Object to be drawn, it needs to
>   add itself to the instance of Renderer's list of objects to draw. This
>   means it needs a pointer to the instance of Renderer, however Renderer
>   also needs to know about Object in order to draw it.

Why is this a problem? If you just need pointers, you can declare the class type upfront:

```
class Object;
class Renderer;
class Engine;
```

Although, even cleaner would be using an Interface class.

**EDIT:**
Do I understand correctly, the problem is that you want to pass Rendered instance to Object, so the object can paint itself using the renderer?

What about the Interface class then:

```
class Paintable
{
    public:
        virtual void paint(Renderer *) = 0;
};

class Object : public Paintable
{
    ...
}
```

All your paintable object will be extending from the interface. This way the Renderer class doesn't need to hold vector of Objects, but vector of pointers to Paintable. (e.g. Renderer is no longer dependent on Object)

**ANSWER:** to second comment
Not sure you have a choice. You need the rendering piece of code to have access to Object's internal data (color, position, etc ...) and to the Renderer handle. Your choices are have the code in Renderer accessing object's internal data. This is, I think, a bad idea, as the Renderer would need to have different code handling different objects, and also possibly accessing private members of the Object. The other way around is to have intelligent objects that can render themselves given the Renderer handle. So they can call: renderer.paintLine(...), etc. Using the Interface class is neat, as the Renderer doen't need to have any knowledge about the Objects it holds.

Comment: The point is I don't want to be passing a pointer to my instance of `Engine` or my instance of `Renderer`.  The way I'm currently doing things is already using a forward declaration of `Renderer` in my `Object` class, but ideally I shouldn't have to pass a pointer to my instance of `Engine` or `Renderer` to my instances of `Object` at all.  This is the circular dependency I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Ideally I'd prefer `Object` to not know about the `Renderer`, but I don't know if my alternative I suggested in my answer is a good idea or not, or whether there is a better alternative to it (and if so, why).

Comment: I have rewritten my question to try and make it more clear what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You would want Object to inherit from Rendered, and Renderer to only be aware of Rendered, not Object (See below):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Renderer;

struct Rendered
{
    virtual void renderMe( Renderer& ) = 0;
  protected:
    //Renderer won't delete me...
    virtual ~Rendered(){}
};

struct Object : Rendered
{
  virtual void renderMe( Renderer& )
  {
    std::cout << "I'm rendered!" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Renderer
{
  void add( Rendered& r )
  {
    renderList_.push_back( & r );
  }
  void remove( Rendered& r );//...use your imagination

  void render()
  {
    for( std::list<Rendered*>::iterator i = renderList_.begin(); i != renderList_.end(); ++i )
    {
      (*i)->renderMe( *this );
    }
  }
  private:
    std::list<Rendered*> renderList_;
};

struct Engine
{
  Renderer& renderer_;
  Object myObject_;
  Engine( Renderer& r )
  : renderer_( r )
  {
    renderer_.add( myObject_ );
  }
  ~Engine()
  {
    renderer_.remove( myObject_ );
  }
};

int test()
{
  Renderer r;
  Enginer e( r );
  r.render();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading your example correctly, the `Object` class inherits from `Rendered`, but still needs to be passed a reference to `Renderer`?

Comment: Yes, but Renderer does not know that it is an Object. To Renderer it is just a Rendered... Hence the dependency is inversed by the inheritance. Now Renderer depends on an abstract type, and never needs to know about Object.

Comment: I may be missing something, but what is the advantage of this compared to what I have right now?  My thinking behind the question was removing the need for `Object` to know about `Renderer`, rather than the other way around.

Comment: I have rewritten my question to try and make it more clear what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You can make renderer an interface. Then rendered only defines what services are required from its perspective. The reason for passing renderer as argument to "renderMe" is for rendered to get hold of essential services (such as canvas etc). This is a typicaly pattern...